# SQL Function: "Query Has No Destination for Result Data"

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm working on what shouldn't be too difficult an SQL function: it takes a few parameters to find a specific course in a table, counts how many people are in that course, compares it to the course's maximum capacity, and returns 1 or 0 as appropriate:

```
drop function if exists room_for_more_students(the_class_name varchar, the_semester_code int);
create function room_for_more_students(the_class_name varchar, the_semester_code int) 
returns int as $BODY$
begin
    select * from class_offerings as match_table 
    where class_name = the_class_name and semester_code = the_semester_code;
    select count(student_id) from match_table as num_students_in_class;
    select avg(maximum_capacity) from match_table as num_students_allowed_in_class;
    --These will all be the same so "avg" just means "the maximum capacity for the class"
    if  num_students_in_class < num_students_allowed_in_class then return 1;
    else return 0;
    end if;
end
$BODY$
language plpgsql;
```

This doesn't really seem like it should be all that complex to implement, and the function creates without issue, but every time I try and invoke it through psycopg2 I receive:

```
ProgrammingError: query has no destination for result data
HINT: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead
```

I have tried experimenting with PERFORM instead, but any combination I try seems to either keep the same issue or create a host of new ones. I've also done some research on this as there are a few other posts about the same issue, but the majority of the time the answer seems to be that the user hasn't added specific return statements, which I have. I'm completely out of ideas and would appreciate any input possible.

Comment: Add `return query` and after it put what you want to return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case, you must declare some variable and assign it with the result of query. You can not run a query without assign its result to nowhere.

I update your function as below:

```
    drop function if exists room_for_more_students(the_class_name varchar, the_semester_code int);
    create function room_for_more_students(the_class_name varchar, the_semester_code int) 
    returns int as 
    $BODY$
    DECLARE
        num_students_allowed_in_class numeric;
        num_students_in_class numeric;
    begin

        WITH match_table AS (
                        select *     
                        from class_offerings 
                        where class_name = the_class_name and semester_code = the_semester_code
                )
          select count(student_id), avg(maximum_capacity)
            INTO num_students_in_class, num_students_allowed_in_class
            from match_table;

        if  num_students_in_class
```

Hopefully it match your request!